# bootstrap datepicker-component shows result only in first textbox after clonning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am cloning bootstrap datepicker-component but after cloning its only working for first datepicker not for the dynamically added datepickers. Here is my code.

**JQUERY**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '#datepicker-component', function(){
    $(this).datepicker('show');
  });

  $('.adQuiz').on('click', function(){
    var dateId = $('.quiz-box:last').attr('id');
    dateId++;
    var clonedQuiz = $('.quiz-box:first').clone(true, true).attr('id', dateId);    
    clonedQuiz.find('#datepicker-component').datepicker(); 
    clonedQuiz.appendTo('.quiz-sec');
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="quiz-sec" style="padding:15px; margin:15px 0 15px 0; border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.8);">               
  <div class="quiz-box" id="1">                                   
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Assignments, Exams and Quizes</label><br/>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="assignments" placeholder="Enter Assignments, Exams and Quizes" name="assignments[]" style="display:inline-block;"/>
    </div>
    <div id="datepicker-component" class="input-group date col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div> <!-- end quiz-box -->
</div> <!-- end quiz-sec -->
<span class="adQuiz" style="font-weight: bold; cursor:pointer; padding-left:2px; color:rgb(43, 106, 148); ">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add More Assignments, Exams and Quizes
</span>
```

I think I am missing something, I have tried several solutions but nothing worked. Please help me in this regard, your suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thank You.